How to model a chain of logical OR Constraints involving divisions and Binary Variables with equivalence relation?
I am currently employed as a network engineer, focusing on network optimization. I've encountered a situation where a Boolean OR chain seems apt for modeling a job completion problem. Building on a previous discussion and after some exchange with the engineering teams, I have decided to create a follow up question and hope to improve my model from your expertise.
Particularly, I need to express the following Boolean OR chain as optimization constraint for my task. Each chain is defined for the case of $y_i=1$ and $y_i=0$
The first Boolean OR chain is:
$$\left[ y_1 = 1 \iff L_1 \le \frac{a_1}{x} \le U_1 \right] \lor \left[ y_2 = 1 \iff L_2 \le \frac{a_2}{x} \le U_2 \right] \lor \dots \lor \left[ y_n = 1 \iff L_n \le \frac{a_n}{x} \le U_n \right]$$
$$\left[ y_1 = 0 \iff 0\le x \le \epsilon \right] \lor \left[ y_2 = 0 \iff  0 \le x \le \epsilon \right] \lor \dots \lor \left[ y_n = 0 \iff 0 \le x \le \epsilon \right]$$
The second Boolean OR chain is more general because it is applied for individual $x_n$:
$$\left[ y_1 = 1 \iff L_1 \le \frac{a_1}{x_1} \le U_1 \right] \lor \left[ y_2 = 1 \iff L_2 \le \frac{a_2}{x_2} \le U_2 \right] \lor \dots \lor \left[ y_n = 1 \iff L_n \le \frac{a_n}{x_n} \le U_n \right]$$
$$\left[ y_1 = 0 \iff 0 \le x_1 \le \epsilon \right] \lor \left[ y_2 = 0 \iff 0 \le x_2 \le \epsilon \right] \lor \dots \lor \left[ y_n = 0 \iff 0 \le x_n \le \epsilon \right]$$

$x$ and $x_i$ are a continuous decision variable constrained by $0 \le x
    \le 1$. In our practical application, to avoid division by zero, we
replace $0$ with a small number $\epsilon$. When $y_i=0$, this $\epsilon$ number will come into play.

All the bounds $U_i$ (starting time), $L_i$ (completion time) as well as the system parameters $a_i$ are
strictly positive numbers.

$y_i$ are boolean decision variables but the starting and completion time is only applied when $y_i = 1$. Specifically speaking, when $y_i=0$ the system will not do
anything so there is no starting time requirement $U_i$ and there is
no completion time requirement $L_i$. However, this will cause the division by zero error if not handle properly. Also, the fractions $\frac{a_n}{x}$ and $\frac{a_n}{x_n}$ can take on any positive value they want but usually we want these fractions to be as small as possible to save energy. We are pretty sure that  y_i = 1 most of the time. The case for y_i = 0 do happen but not as much.


Given these constraints, I seek guidance on the best methods to effectively formulate these constraints.
P/S: I have make a mistake about the case $y_i=0$.  Therefore, I have editted my question

What exactly do you mean by $\cup$? Is it something logical OR?

Yes yes it is logical or

Do you have $L$ and $U$ reversed?

Sorry I think I make a mistake. The order of L and U have been reversed. My deepest apology

For the first boolean chain, following @RobPratt's notation from the previous question:
You want to enforce
$$\bigvee_{i=1}^n \left(y_i = 1\Leftrightarrow L_i \le \frac{a_i}{x} \le U_i \right)$$
Equivalently,
$$\bigvee_{i=1}^n \left(y_i = 1\Leftrightarrow\frac{a_i}{U_i} \le x \le \frac{a_i}{L_i} \right)$$
Introduce binary decision variables $z_i$ and impose
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \ge 1 \tag1\label1 \\
 -\frac{a_i}{U_i}\cdot(1- z_i)+\frac{a_i}{U_i} y_i \le x &\le \frac{a_i}{L_i}+(1-\frac{a_i}{L_i})\cdot(1- y_i) +1\cdot (1- z_i)\quad \forall i\tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ enforce $\bigvee z_i$, inequalities $(2)$ are big-M contraints which enforce
$$
z_i=1 \implies  
 \left (
y_i = 1\implies \frac{a_i}{U_i} \le x \le \frac{a_i}{L_i} \right) 
$$
and
$$
z_i=1 \implies  
\left( 
y_i = 0\implies 0 \le x \le 1 
\right) 
$$
For the second boolean chain, you can replace $x$ with $x_i$ in $(2)$.

If you want $$
z_i=1 \implies  
\left( 
y_i = 0\implies x=0
\right) 
$$
adapt $(2)$ as follows:
$$
-\frac{a_i}{U_i}\cdot(1- z_i)+\frac{a_i}{U_i} y_i \le x \le \frac{a_i}{L_i}y_i +1\cdot (1- z_i)
$$
If you want $$
z_i=1 \implies  
\left( 
y_i = 0\implies 0 \le x \le \epsilon
\right) 
$$
adapt $(2)$ as follows:
$$
-\frac{a_i}{U_i}\cdot(1- z_i)+\frac{a_i}{U_i} y_i \le x \le \frac{a_i}{L_i}y_i+\epsilon\cdot(1-y_i) +1\cdot (1- z_i)
$$

Do you infer $\cup$ is the same as $\lor$?

yes indeed, it is clear from the previous question.

@Kuifje If the sum of $z_i=1$ then does it become XOR chain ?

Yes indeed, if $\sum_ z_i = 1$, exactly one of the inequalities will hold (exclusive OR). If $\sum_ z_i \ge 1$, at least one will hold (inclusive OR).

@Kuifje I am sorry I did not get your idea, can you point out what thing have to be big in $(2)$. I see that you said it is big M but I am not sure what have to be big ?

The left hand term, for example, can be simplified to  $(0-\frac{a_i}{U_i})\cdot(2- z_i-y_i)+\frac{a_i}{U_i}=-M\cdot(2- z_i-y_i)+\frac{a_i}{U_i}$.

@Kuifje, are you sure to impose $\iff$ instead of $\implies$?

Where exxactly?

@Kuifje, in the inner clauses, where I mean how do you enforce $\left(y_i = 0\rightarrow\frac{a_i}{U_i} \ge x \ge \frac{a_i}{L_i} \right)$?

There may be some ambiguity in the question, or more likely I may have misunderstood: I understood the implications as 1/ $y_i=1 \implies \frac{a_i}{U_i} \le x \le \frac{a_i}{L_i}$ and 2/ $y_i=0 \implies 0 \le x \le 1$. But I do realize this may not be what OP was asking (?). @TuongNguyenMinh would you mind confirming this?

@Kuifje well what I want is a two way relationship (forward and reverse direction) in the case of 1/
$\left[ y_1 = 1 \iff L_1 \le \frac{a_1}{x} \le U_1 \right] \lor \left[ y_2 = 1 \iff L_2 \le \frac{a_2}{x} \le U_2 \right] \lor \dots \lor \left[ y_n = 1 \iff L_n \le \frac{a_n}{x} \le U_n \right]$

In this case, @A.Omidi, I believe the answer is ok as it satisfies both conditions 1/ and 2/.

@Kuifje I have make a mistake, for the case of $y_i=0$ then $0 \le x_i \le \epsilon$  where $\epsilon$ is a very small number.  WOuld you kindly help me again. Thank you so much ! Also, I must apology for this inconvenience, we engineer do make mistake when it come to the small details.

@TuongNguyenMinh, if you have the above condition, it may cause a conflict with your first Iff, $\iff$, definition as I said in my previous comment.

Oh I see but do these new condition incur conflict if we abandoned equivalency and opt for implication only ?

@TuongNguyenMinh. I am unsure if I can understand what you mean well. You said, (if y=1 <=> L <= a/x <= U). It actually translates as two different expressions. First, (if y=1 => L <= x <= U) and second (if L <= x <= U => y=1). I think the latter may cause a conflict with (if y=0 => 0 <= x <= eps). You have to check that!

Oh I see then I think I will accept the answer ! For the nitty gritty detail our teams will have to hard code the case. Currently, it seems that the original answer works well !
